# Problema com pontos que não se juntam as linhas no ggplot

Tags: r

Estou com o seguinte arquivo de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue para leitura dos dados

```
structure(list(ano = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), Regiao = c("BaixadaFluminense", 
"Capital", "GrandeNiterói", "Interior", "BaixadaFluminense", 
"Capital", "GrandeNiterói", "Interior", "BaixadaFluminense", 
"Capital", "GrandeNiterói", "Interior"), total = c(17544L, 42426L, 
9129L, 10174L, 18661L, 34878L, 8713L, 4438L, 11791L, 21743L, 
4866L, 2475L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), groups = structure(list(
    ano = 2018:2020, .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8, 9:12), ptype = integer(0), 
    class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), 
    class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

E quero gerar um gráfico que contenha no eixo y o total, no x o ano e a região fique na legenda. O problema é que quando vou gerar o gráfico com o código abaixo os pontos da mesma região não ficam ligados por uma linha.

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=as.factor(ano), y=total))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=Regiao))+
  labs(x="Ano", y="Total")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10, colour="Black"),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.4, colour = "black"),
  axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.4, colour = "black"),
  legend.title =element_text(size = 10, colour="Black"))+
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Paired", name="Região")
```

Gera o seguinte gráfico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu só conseguir deixar os pontos ligados por uma linha quando usei o **facet_grid**, mas com o código abaixo, aparece 4x o eixo y, e eu quero que fique tudo em um gráfico só, com somente um eixo y, semelhante ao primeiro gráfico. Alguém sabe alguma forma de eu conseguir deixar o primeiro gráfico com os pontos juntos por uma linha ou alguma outra forma que eu consiga fazer isso ?

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=ano, y=total))+
  geom_point(color="blue")+
  geom_line(color="black")+
  facet_grid(Regiao~.)+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10, colour="Black"),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.4, colour = "black"),
  axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.4, colour = "black"),
  legend.title =element_text(size = 10, colour="Black"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Obrigada @MarcusNunes, fiz a correção.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As linhas precisam de um eixo X contínuo; deve usar `x = ano` e não `x = as.factor(ano)`. Use a opção `breaks` da `scale_x_continuous` para controlar os intervalos e fazer com que as marcas sejam de ano em ano:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dados, aes(ano, total, colour = Regiao)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = dados$ano)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada Carlos!!